# Audio CD isn't readable by computer but plays in a CD player

Tags: linux, compact-disc, optical-drive, ripping, audio-cd

I'm using my fedora laptop to rip audio cdroms to flac, using `abcde` to do so.

I happened on a cd that can't be read by my laptop(abcde complains that "cd could not be read. Perhaps there's no CD in the player?", and other cdplayers similarly fail), but can be played fine on my cdrom player.

It's a Ryko cd.

Anyone has an idea on how to proceed(to read the cd on my laptop)?

Edit: `cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc` output:

```
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'TSSTcorp'
Identification : 'CDDVDW SN-208FB '
Revision       : 'TM00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x0000 (Reserved/Unknown)
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
```

Edit: `isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0` output:

```
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), test unit ready scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x2 Not Ready, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x30 Qual 0x00 (incompatible medium installed) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 0.013s timeout 20s
isoinfo: No such file or directory. Unable to open /dev/sr0
```

Comment: There are CDs with funny protection schemes (often several sessions). What's the output of `cdrecord -minfo` (or any other program you have that can display sessions and toc)?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause #1:** Most of the times, in my case, the issue has been a worn disc or unclean disc drive. Laptop disc drives are especially picky about discs. There are several things you can do about it:

1. Clean your disc drive using a cleaning pack or, if you have DIY skills, by opening it up and cleaning both its lens and gears.
2. Clean your disc, using a disc cleaning solution or non-alcoholic window cleaning solution.
3. Use another computer that has a different disc drive.

**Cause #2:** It is possible that a disc protection scheme is preventing you, although I myself haven't encountered one. It is, however, possible to connect your audio CD player to your computer with an audio cable and use [Audacity](https://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/) to record its output. I did this convert my cassettes to audio files.